# ubuntuphone does not connect to ubuntu desktop

Tags: usb, ubuntu-touch, connection

My BQ Ubuntuphone is not recognized by my Ubuntu-PC. Is there any special setting on either side to enable the connection?

Comment: I installed a new version of libmtp

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/libmtp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt full-upgrade

Now the phone is at least recognized but I cannot copy any file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the latest version of `libmtp`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/libmtp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

This should make it so your phone is at least recognized. **To access your data, you'll have to unlock your homescreen on the phone.**